# PPM not Viewable

Tags: powershell, console, ppm

I output a python script to a file through windows powershell using `py test.py > image.ppm` the output file perfectly formatted with the exact number of pixels and such, but for some reason it cannot be opened/viewed unless I copy and paste it to a new file. Any suggestions would be awesome, thank you!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/01/18/redirecting-binary-output-in-powershell/) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason powershell outputs text in a different way from CMD. Using CMD fixes this issue.